# Lagrangian formulation of classical spin chains

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, spin-models, spin-chains

Is there a way to construct a Lagrangian formulation of the classical dynamics of a spin chain - say a Heisenberg or XY chain? The Hamiltonians here are obvious.